# Cannot rotate x axis labels in ggplot2 facet graphs in r

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, geom-bar

Can anyone help out with a task? 
I've been trying to run a part of code that creates a `facet_wrap()` graph in r, and it worked very well for my porpouse but the x axis labels are overlapping each other. 
I need to rotate them 45 degrees. 
I've been trying to run this code for the porpouse and it did create the graph, but the x axis label didn't rotate as I expected.

Here is the code:

```
for (x in unique(clss_perc_factor7$Horto)){
  ggsave(paste('barplot_esp40', x, sep = '_'), 
         ggplot(clss_perc_factor7[clss_perc_factor7$Horto == x,], 
                aes(x = Classe, 
                    y = Freq_perc)) +
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
           theme_bw() +
           geom_bar(stat = 'identity', 
                    colour = 'black', 
                    fill = '#66CC99') +
           facet_wrap(~ CD_TALHAO) +
           labs(x = 'Classe de Espaçamento', 
                y = 'Nº de Indivíduos (%)', 
                title = 'Distribuição do Espaçamento em Classes'),
         dpi = 'retina',
         device = 'png')
}
```

## Given that:

- clss_perc_factor7 is the data frame with more then one forest garden ("Horto" - in the loop).
- In each forest garden there are different productive units ("CD_TALHAO" - in `facet_wrap()`)
- That's why I'm using a for loop to plot the graphs.

OBS: The part `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)...` which was supposed to align the title to center isn't working either.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: You could try `axis.text.x.bottom` and `axis.text.x.top` if the regular one doesn't work.

Comment: As per this article, with v3.3.0 you can just add `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))` to avoid overlapping labels: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey @Magnus Nordmo , thanks for the answer, but with this code, the only thing that rotates is the label of the variable which was used to facet. I want to change the angle of the x axis labels. Do you know how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got it! The only problem with my script was the order of the layers. I didn't know it interferes on ploting. Thanks man!

Comment: Actually, the problem wasn't the order, but the```theme_bw()``` that I was using.

Comment: I see! I should have picked up on that. Any adjustment to `theme` will be nullified when adding a pre-built theme. The solution is to add custom `theme` elements last.